# On which Linux Distributions do the "stat" and "service" commands run?

Tags: linux, bash

On which Linux Distributions do the following commands run?

- `service $servicename status`
- `stat -c \"%a\" /var/log/$filename`

For example assuming `$servicename="apache2"` and `$filename="syslog"`.

Comment: This question is probably more suited for the Superadmin sister page. See the link at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Also, the two questions don't seem to have anything in common.  The `stat` command is installed with GNU coreutils by standard, whereas `service` is a completely unrelated command for an unrelated subsystem which is the default on some distros, but not on others.

Answer (score 2):

- `stat` is part of `coreutils` and part of the GNU project. Any major GNU/Linux distribution will offer this package. Note that minimal environments like [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) may instead offer their own, limited version of `stat`.
- `service` is part of `sysvinit-tools` and not part of GNU. Only distributions using System-V-style init scripts will offer it.

[Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/) offers a comparison of different distributions and also tracks the versions of a selected set of packages.

Note that services may have different names accross distributions as well. For example `apache2` may be called `httpd` instead.

Comment: Am I able to use the mentioned commands on all Linux distributions?

Comment: No. `stat` is probably not the problem, but not all of them use SysvInit, so `service` won't be available everywhwere.

Comment: Is there a query that works for most Linux distributions to check a service?

Comment: No. You can check for processes using `ps` on almost any system, but this has some pitfalls, e.g. processes do not always map to services 1:1.

Comment: Generally, I would suggest focusing on _Upstart_, _systemd_ and _SysVinit_, but I don't know if that will fit your scenario. If you want to implement something portable, it will not be enough to just ask for a query command here, you'll have to (1) build a list of relevant distributions - you can't support 600 of them, (2) read the documentation of the distributions' init system, (3) implement an adapter for each distribution and (4) test on these different systems.